# os.system(<command>) execution through Python :: Limitations?

Tags: python, arduino, os.system

I'm writing a python (ver 2.7) script to automate the set of commands in this Getting Started [example](http://inotool.org/quickstart) for [INOTOOL](http://inotool.org/).

Problem: When I run this entire script, I repeatedly encounter these errors:

```
Current Directory is not empty  
No project is found in this directory  
No project is found in this directory
```

But, when I run a first script only up till the code line marked, and manually type in the next three lines, or when I run these last three lines (starting from the "ino init -t blink" line) after manually accessing the beep folder, then I am able to successfully execute the same code.

Is there a limitation with os.system() that I'm encountering?

My code:

```
import os,sys  
def upload()  
    os.system("cd /home/pi/Downloads")  
    os.system("mkdir beep")  
    os.system("cd beep") #will refer to this code junction in question description  
    os.system("ino init -t blink")  
    os.system("ino build")  
    os.system("ino upload")  
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: @shamoit, I added an example using subprocess.check_call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and os.mkdir to make the directory, you can pass the current working directory `cwd` to `check_call`so you actually execute the command in the directory:

```
from subprocess import check_call
import os 
def upload(): 
    d = "/home/pi/Downloads/beep"
    os.mkdir(d)
    check_call(["ino", "init", "-t", "blink"],cwd=d)  
    check_call(["ino", "build"],cwd=d)  
    check_call(["ino", "upload"],cwd=d)
```

A non-zero exit status will raise  [CalledProcessError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) which you may want to catch but once successful you know the commands all returned a 0 exit status.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when `os.system()` commands are run for `cd` , it does not actually change the current directory for the python process' context. From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) -

> **os.system(command)**
>
> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command.

So even though you are changing directory in os.system() call, the next os.system call still occurs in same directory. Which could be causing your issue.

You shoud try using [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the directory instead of `os.system()` calls.

The Best would be to use `subprocess` module as @PadraicCunningham explains in his answer.

Comment: os.system should not be used at all

Comment: Added that best would be to use subprocess module.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham also, just as an FYI , can you tell why os.system is bad? I understand subprocess is better.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just tried it, and it does the trick alright :) Also, same question as Anand - how is os.system bad and why is subprocess better?

Comment: subprocess is a replacement for os.system and other functions as per the first lines of https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.

Comment: But then why is `os.system()` bad?

Comment: Why do you think it has been replaced? The subprocess module is way more powerful than os.system,it will be actively developed and improved. Why use something that you are encouraged to replace with something else?